# Does being in the area of effect of a spell at the time of casting count as "entering"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does being in the area of effect of a spell at the time of casting count as "entering"?

For example when casting Web:

> Each creature that starts its turn in the webs or that enters them during its turn must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature is Restrained as long as it remains in the webs or until it breaks free.

If it did not count it would imply that if you cast web on someone next to you, you would not get the chance to move the same turn with the benefit of them being restrained.

Comment: It looks like your Question already has an answer elsewhere. If that does not answer your question, consider editing to note how your question is different and what questions still remain.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose It should be noted that Moonbeam text says "on a turn", while Web says "during its turn".  RAW this is an important difference. Also Web doesn't say "enter for the first time". The mechanic seems slightly different.

Comment: @HellSaint this was my thought as well probably should have worded it better...

Comment: @MarkOmo note that while this makes a different question, the answer should be the same. Web does not restrain the opponent when you cast it on them (they don't even need to make a saving throw by that time.)

Comment: @HellSaint: That does not seem to make a difference for the purposes of what it means to "enter". The question and answer both fully encompass this one still in my opinion.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Agreed. For some reason my mind read this question slightly different. Probably due to the last two lines. Now I read it again and you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

You only count as entering an effect when you physically move into it.

Since entering an AOE is not a defined activity in the rules, we can use plain English.

> come or go into (a place)

Being within the area when it is designated does not constitute going into it.

---

This is also clarified in [Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-april-2016) (the official rules answers article) where it says:

> Our design intent for such spells is this: a creature enters the area of effect when the creature passes into it. **Creating the area of effect on the creature or moving it onto the creature doesn’t count.**

(**Emphasis** mine)